# Integration involving $\log_2(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, fractions

Having a hard time going about this problem:

$$\int{\frac{\ln(2)\log_2(x)}{x}}$$

I believe $\ln(2)$ would be considered a constant, so than the equation would then changed to:

$$\ln(2)\int{\dfrac{\log_2(x)}{x}}$$

That's about all I've got.

Comment: $\log_2(x)$ = $\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln{2}}$

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac1x=(\ln x)'$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\log_2(x)=\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$ then your anti-derivative becomes

$$\int\frac{\ln x}{x}dx=\int\frac1x\times\ln xdx=\frac12(\ln x)^2+C $$